# Is it possible to migrate a ContentDB between farms with different build

Tags: 2013, content-database

I am wondering if it is possible to migrate a Content Database(using **Mount-SPDatabase**) from a source farm which has 2013 but an older build version, to a destination farm which also has 2013 but a newer build version.

As far as I know, the only time SharePoint automatically upgrades a database is when you carry it between versions such as 2010 to 2013, or 2013 to 2016 etc.

Can someone please clarify?

I have a source and destination, which seem to have same build number:

> Major  Minor  Build  Revision
>
> ---
>
> 15     0      4719   1000

but I suspect my source has May CU (which does not need sp1 to be installed) and my destination have sp1 + may cu.

I am getting this error:

```
Mount-SPContentDatabase : This content database has a schema version which is not supported in this farm.
```

Can I get this working? From past experience, I've never managed to get an older-patched content database working on a more-recently-patched farm, so would love to get some clarification on that.

Thanks
Ova

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but before monunting, run Test-SPContentDatabase (which will say something like your error message above), and then Mount-SPContentDatabase.

Finally [Upgrade-SPContentDatabase](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607813.aspx) which will upgrade the schema version of the Content_DB to the schema version in the destination farm.

If this fails, you can always [Restore content from unattached content databases in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh269602.aspx).

Comment: Hi, Are you sure Upgrade-SPContentDatabase will work before mounting? no matter how I try it says Upgrade-SPContentDatabase : The content database could not be found.    My command is like this:  Upgrade-SPContentDatabase -Name DBNAME  -WebApplication http://WEBAPPURL/ -ServerInstance SQLINSTANCENAME

Comment: I might remember things wrong. Try to mount it first and then upgrade

Comment: Problem is it doesn't mount because of the error above :) But thanks anyway.

Comment: @ova I've updated my answer, which hopefully help you along the way

Answer (score 1):

You can mount a content database from lower build version farm to higher build version.

But the error you are seeing is due to version mismatch...means you are restoring higher version to lower version farm.

Run this command on both farm to get the version number

```
(get-spfarm).buildversion
```

Comment: I have already did that, and the result is in my post: 15 0 4719 1000
both farms have this version.

Comment: Now could you please check via central admin, upgrade and migration> patch status...see if source farm has any extra patch installed. Compare that page with source and destination

Comment: Hi, how is it possible to mount a content database from lower build to higher build please? I cannot see any way else than building an intermediate server, upgrade that db there and then mount it to newer version? Is there another way? When I check central admin, the only difference between 2 farm is some security KB's which seem to affect whole thing. Is there a way to complete this restore without installing any patch on both destination and source?

Comment: it is mount command, when you attach a lower end DB to Higher version farm. if the source farm is higher then there is no way to restore that DB into lower version farm, Unless you use a 3 rd party tool like sharegate,metalogix...other option is apply those security patch to destination farm

Comment: But the Mount-SPDatabase command fails with this error I mention in the post?  My destination farm has some newer patches on it, my source doesn't have them, I don't think it is possible to restore an older content db to a newer one.

Comment: I mounted many databases from lower farm to higher many times. Check the logs for more clue, did you try using central admin?

Comment: did you  ever get the "This content database has a schema version which is not supported in this farm." error? Yes, I will check the logs, thanks

Comment: I don't remember I get that

Answer (score 0):

I have compared The Central Administration > Manage Patch Status page between 2 farms and discovered that the target farm was missing 5 Security Kb updates. I applied them and the Mount-SPContentDatabase command worked. 
So   although the 2 farms had the same build number,  those several security updates were blocking it somehow!(Actually the target farm is sp1+may cu but the source farm only had may cu I think as may cu is independent of sp1)

All resolved now. Thanks for your suggestions and answers.